# Retrofit - Why JSON from API convert to Null Java Object Using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I try to receive `JSON` API using Retrofit but when `response.body();` it always show `null` value.

Here my `JSON` :

```
{
    "data": {},
    "status": {
        "id": 0,
        "msg": "yes"
    }
}
```

And here my object `Header.java` :

```
public class Header {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private MyData myData;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private MyStatus myStatus;

    //getter setter here , i cut for not too long code
}
```

Here `MyData` class :

> //nothing code here, cause JSON tag data always nothing , tag exist
>   but value is always nothing

Here `MyStatus` class :

```
@SerializedName("id")
private int status;

@SerializedName("msg")
private String message;
```

And this is snippet of `MyOtherClass.jav`a (after callback of enqueue) :

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Header> call, Response<Header> response) {
                        Header myHeader = response.body();
//I cut for not too long code
```

When i check `myHeader` value, it is always `null`.

Anyone can explain why?

Comment: could you post your retrofit initialization code ?

Comment: print the response.code and check if response.isSuccess

Comment: Yes response is success @diegoveloper

Comment: Could you post retrofit related code. atleast in this server hit related code.

Comment: have you got your response like this:
@POST("{path}")
Call<Header> getHeaderData(@Path("path") String path);
can you check this and try print log in onResponse for response.code as @diegoveloper said and do one more thing Log for response.body()